# Read value from DataStore with flow before updating it

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm quite new using Kotlin's `flows` and Jetpack's `DataStore`. But I'm writing a list of custom objects (serialized as a JSON) which I want to update before inserting a new value.

Therefore when wanting to insert a new element, previously I have to read the current value, therefore I'm collecting the values from the flow, adding the new one and then writing on the `DataStore`. The issue is that once the `DataStore`has finished writing the values I receive a new event from the `flow` I got subscribe, therefore I'm in a loop writing the values.

My question is, is there any way to collecting the values from the `flow` just once or cancel the `flow`after I've read the values, or is there a better way to manage this situation with `DataStore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get only data from datastore like this

```
   // This function belongs on your datastore file
   suspend fun getMyCustomData(): String {
        val preferences = dataStore.data.first()
        return preferences[MY_CUSTOM_KEY] ?: ""
   }
```

And after reading the value you can update your object without getting stuck in a loop.